# Inject RTCM correction data to GPS M8P Module

Tags: python, serial-port, gps

I am trying to inject NTRIP RTCM corrections into a M8P GPS module using a raspberry pi. The GPS module is hooked up via serial port (/dev/serial0). I am receiving the rtcm correction packets but how do I forward those to the GPS module? I tried using serial.write(data) but it is not doing anything. What is the correct way to inject the RTCM correction data into the GPS from a Raspberry pi? I am using a public base station.

```
"""
 NTRIP client module
 based on client from http://github.com/jcmb/NTRIP
"""

import socket
import sys
import datetime
import base64
import time
import errno
import rtcm3
import ssl
from optparse import OptionParser
import serial

version = 0.1
useragent = "NTRIP MAVProxy/%.1f" % version


class NtripError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, inner_exception=None):
        self.message = message
        self.inner_exception = inner_exception
        self.exception_info = sys.exc_info()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


class NtripClient(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 user="",
                 port=2101,
                 caster="",
                 mountpoint="",
                 host=False,
                 lat=46,
                 lon=122,
                 height=1212,
                 ssl=False,
                 V2=False,
                 ):
        if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
            user = bytearray(user, 'ascii')
        self.user = base64.b64encode(user)
        self.port = port
        self.caster = caster
        self.mountpoint = mountpoint
        if not self.mountpoint.startswith("/"):
            self.mountpoint = "/" + self.mountpoint
        self.setPosition(lat, lon)
        self.height = height
        self.ssl = ssl
        self.host = host
        self.V2 = V2
        self.socket = None
        self.found_header = False
        self.sent_header = False
        # RTCM3 parser
        self.rtcm3 = rtcm3.RTCM3()
        self.last_id = None
        if self.port == 443:
            # force SSL on port 443
            self.ssl = True

    def setPosition(self, lat, lon):
        self.flagN = "N"
        self.flagE = "E"
        if lon > 180:
            lon = (lon-360)*-1
            self.flagE = "W"
        elif lon < 0 and lon >= -180:
            lon = lon*-1
            self.flagE = "W"
        elif lon < -180:
            lon = lon+360
            self.flagE = "E"
        else:
            self.lon = lon
        if lat < 0:
            lat = lat*-1
            self.flagN = "S"
        self.lonDeg = int(lon)
        self.latDeg = int(lat)
        self.lonMin = (lon-self.lonDeg)*60
        self.latMin = (lat-self.latDeg)*60

    def getMountPointString(self):
        userstr = self.user
        if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
            userstr = str(userstr, 'ascii')
        mountPointString = "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\nAuthorization: Basic %s\r\n" % (
            self.mountpoint, useragent, userstr)
        if self.host or self.V2:
            hostString = "Host: %s:%i\r\n" % (self.caster, self.port)
            mountPointString += hostString
        if self.V2:
            mountPointString += "Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/2.0\r\n"
        mountPointString += "\r\n"
        return mountPointString

    def getGGAString(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        ggaString = "GPGGA,%02d%02d%04.2f,%02d%011.8f,%1s,%03d%011.8f,%1s,1,05,0.19,+00400,M,%5.3f,M,," % (
                     now.hour, now.minute, now.second, self.latDeg, self.latMin, self.flagN,
                     self.lonDeg, self.lonMin, self.flagE, self.height)
        checksum = self.calculateCheckSum(ggaString)
        return "$%s*%s\r\n" % (ggaString, checksum)

    def calculateCheckSum(self, stringToCheck):
        xsum_calc = 0
        for char in stringToCheck:
            xsum_calc = xsum_calc ^ ord(char)
        return "%02X" % xsum_calc

    def get_ID(self):
        '''get ID of last packet'''
        return self.last_id

    def read(self):
        if self.socket is None:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.connect()
            return None

        if not self.found_header:
            if not self.sent_header:
                self.sent_header = True
                time.sleep(0.1)
                mps = self.getMountPointString()
                if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
                    mps = bytearray(mps, 'ascii')
                try:
                    self.socket.sendall(mps)
                except Exception:
                    self.socket = None
                    return None
            try:
                casterResponse = self.socket.recv(4096)
            except ssl.SSLWantReadError:
                    return None
            except IOError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    return None
                self.socket = None
                casterResponse = ''
            if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
                casterResponse = str(casterResponse, 'ascii')
            header_lines = casterResponse.split("\r\n")
            for line in header_lines:
                if line == "":
                    self.found_header = True
                if line.find("SOURCETABLE") != -1:
                    raise NtripError("Mount point does not exist")
                elif line.find("401 Unauthorized") != -1:
                    raise NtripError("Unauthorized request")
                elif line.find("404 Not Found") != -1:
                    raise NtripError("Mount Point does not exist")
                elif line.find(" 200 OK") != -1:
                    # Request was valid
                    try:
                        gga = self.getGGAString()
                        if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
                            gga = bytearray(gga, 'ascii')
                        self.socket.sendall(gga)
                    except Exception:
                        self.socket = None
                        return None
            return None
        # normal data read
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.socket.recv(1)
            except ssl.SSLWantReadError:
                    return None
            except IOError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    return None
                self.socket.close()
                self.socket = None
                return None
            except Exception:
                self.socket.close()
                self.socket = None
                return None
            if len(data) == 0:
                self.socket.close()
                self.socket = None
                return None
            if self.rtcm3.read(data):
                self.last_id = self.rtcm3.get_packet_ID()
                return self.rtcm3.get_packet()

    def connect(self):
        '''connect to NTRIP server'''
        self.sent_header = False
        self.found_header = False
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        if self.ssl:
            sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
        try:
            error_indicator = sock.connect_ex((self.caster, self.port))
        except Exception:
            return False
        if error_indicator == 0:
            sock.setblocking(0)
            self.socket = sock
            self.rtcm3.reset()
            return True
        return False

    def readLoop(self):
        while True:
            data = self.read()

            if data is None:
                continue

            ##ADDED
            ser = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 9600)
            ser.write(data)
            ##

            print("got: ", len(data))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    usage = "NtripClient.py [options] [caster] [port] mountpoint"
    parser = OptionParser(version=version, usage=usage)
    parser.add_option("-u", "--user", type="string", dest="user", default="IBS", help="The Ntripcaster username.  Default: %default")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--password", type="string", dest="password", default="IBS", help="The Ntripcaster password. Default: %default")
    parser.add_option("-o", "--org", type="string", dest="org", help="Use IBSS and the provided organization for the user. Caster and Port are not needed in this case Default: %default")
    parser.add_option("-b", "--baseorg", type="string", dest="baseorg", help="The org that the base is in. IBSS Only, assumed to be the user org")
    parser.add_option("-t", "--latitude", type="float", dest="lat", default=50.09, help="Your latitude.  Default: %default")
    parser.add_option("-g", "--longitude", type="float", dest="lon", default=8.66, help="Your longitude.  Default: %default")
    parser.add_option("-e", "--height", type="float", dest="height", default=1200, help="Your ellipsoid height.  Default: %default")
    parser.add_option("-s", "--ssl", action="store_true", dest="ssl", default=False, help="Use SSL for the connection")
    parser.add_option("-H", "--host", action="store_true", dest="host", default=False, help="Include host header, should be on for IBSS")
    parser.add_option("-2", "--V2", action="store_true", dest="V2", default=False, help="Make a NTRIP V2 Connection")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    ntripArgs = {}

    ntripArgs['lat'] = options.lat
    ntripArgs['lon'] = options.lon
    ntripArgs['height'] = options.height
    ntripArgs['host'] = options.host

    ntripArgs['user'] = "GRSM:GRSM"
    ntripArgs['caster'] = "ntrip.nps.gov"
    ntripArgs['port'] = 2101
    ntripArgs['mountpoint'] = "GRSM_RTCM3x"
    

    n = NtripClient(**ntripArgs)
    n.readLoop()
```

**rtcm3.py

```
'''Decode RTCM v3 messages'''

RTCMv3_PREAMBLE = 0xD3
POLYCRC24 = 0x1864CFB

import struct

class RTCM3:
    def __init__(self, debug=False):
        self.crc_table = None
        self.debug = debug
        self.reset()

    def get_packet(self):
        '''return bytearray of last parsed packet'''
        return self.parsed_pkt

    def get_packet_ID(self):
        '''get get of packet, or None'''
        if self.parsed_pkt is None or len(self.parsed_pkt) < 8:
            return None
        id, = struct.unpack('>H', self.parsed_pkt[3:5])
        id >>= 4
        return id

    def reset(self):
        '''reset state'''
        self.pkt = bytearray()
        self.pkt_len = 0
        self.parsed_pkt = None

    def parse(self):
        '''parse packet'''
        parity = self.pkt[-3:]
        crc1 = parity[0] << 16 | parity[1] << 8 | parity[2]
        crc2 = self.crc24(self.pkt[:-3])
        if crc1 != crc2:
            if self.debug:
                print("crc fail len=%u" % len(self.pkt))
            # look for preamble
            idx = self.pkt[1:].find(bytearray([RTCMv3_PREAMBLE]))
            if idx >= 0:
                self.pkt = self.pkt[1+idx:]
                if len(self.pkt) >= 3:
                    self.pkt_len, = struct.unpack('>H', self.pkt[1:3])
                    self.pkt_len &= 0x3ff
                else:
                    self.pkt_len = 0
            else:
                self.reset()
            return False

        # got a good packet
        self.parsed_pkt = self.pkt
        self.pkt = bytearray()
        self.pkt_len = 0
        return True

    def read(self, byte):
        '''read in one byte, return true if a full packet is available'''

        #import random
        #if random.uniform(0,1000) < 1:
        #    return False

        byte = ord(byte)
        if len(self.pkt) == 0 and byte != RTCMv3_PREAMBLE:
            # discard
            return False

        self.pkt.append(byte)
        if self.pkt_len == 0 and len(self.pkt) >= 3:
            self.pkt_len, = struct.unpack('>H', self.pkt[1:3])
            self.pkt_len &= 0x3ff
            if self.pkt_len == 0:
                self.reset()
                return False

        if self.pkt_len > 0 and len(self.pkt) >= 3 + self.pkt_len + 3:
            remainder = self.pkt[6+self.pkt_len:]
            self.pkt = self.pkt[:6+self.pkt_len]
            # got header, packet body and parity
            ret = self.parse()
            self.pkt.extend(remainder)
            return ret

        # need more bytes
        return False

    def crc24(self, bytes):
        '''calculate 24 bit crc'''
        if self.crc_table is None:
            # initialise table
            self.crc_table = [0] * 256
            for i in range(256):
                self.crc_table[i] = i<<16
                for j in range(8):
                    self.crc_table[i] <<= 1
                    if (self.crc_table[i] & 0x1000000):
                        self.crc_table[i] ^= POLYCRC24
        crc = 0
        for b in bytes:
            crc = ((crc<<8)&0xFFFFFF) ^ self.crc_table[(crc>>16) ^ b]
        return crc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    import time
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='RTCM3 parser')

    parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, help="input file")
    parser.add_argument("--debug", action='store_true', help="show errors")
    parser.add_argument("--follow", action='store_true', help="continue reading on EOF")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    rtcm3 = RTCM3(args.debug)
    f = open(args.filename, 'rb')
    while True:
        b = f.read(1)
        if len(b) == 0:
            if args.follow:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                continue
            break
        if rtcm3.read(b):
            print("packet len %u ID %u" % (len(rtcm3.get_packet()), rtcm3.get_packet_ID()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the serial port of your RPI is enabled or not. If not, then follow the enabling process of RPI. Maybe try this https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/enabling-serial-console

Other than that, the RTCM data is pure raw-data in nature, so, you just have to forward it as it is to your gps moudule (without processing anything). If still not working, then the main question arieses which is whether you're getting the right RTCM data from the base station or not.

Comment: Where would I send the RTCM data to the RPI serial port in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't much worked on a python because the processing is slightly slower. Therefore I build the codes in C language, which is much faster. Moreover, long ago, I had made an application based on serial communication, so, I'm sharing some of the modules, which might be helpful to you.

About your query, you've to call the function Serial.write(data) in the loop, also try to put a small(micro-sec) delay in between two data byte delay(10). Lastly, I can't answer where exactly you need to put serial.write() in your application, you just have to put it somewhere, where you're receiving the complete RTCM data, so, you can just push it forward on serial.

Suggestion: Go for the lwirinngPi libraries availabe for the C language. Much suiatable for the raw data processing.

```
#------------Standard Imports------------
import serial

#------------serial variable--------------
Serial_portName    = "/dev/ttyS0"
Serial_BaudRate    = 115200
ComPortReciveFlag  = False
ComPortRecieveBuff = ""


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def ReadSerialData():

  global ComPortRecieveBuff
  global ComPortReciveFlag

          
  if (ser.inWaiting()>0):     
         ComPortRecieveBuff = ser.read()
         sleep(0.03)
         data_left = ser.inWaiting()
         ComPortRecieveBuff += ser.read(data_left)
         ComPortReciveFlag   = True

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def AutoStart_window(self):

   global ComPortRecieveBuff , ComPortReciveFlag

   #--do process here....
   while True:
        #--for receiving 
        #--received_data = ReadSerialData()
        #--if (ComPortReciveFlag == True):
        #--ComPortReciveFlag  = False
        #--process on received data    

        #--for Sending   
        #--ser.reset_output_buffer()
        #--ser.write("# START $".encode()) #incase of string data
        #--for unknown data type
        #--for x in range(data_length)
        #--   ser.write(Txbuffer[x])    

#---------Main Code Starting Point-------- 
#---------Serial ComPort-------- 
ser = serial.Serial (Serial_portName, Serial_BaudRate)
```